# serializing data from multiple table in drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models user and organization. The user model is the default Django model. My organization model looks like below

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=False)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, through='Membership')

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"org_organization"'

class Membership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"org_organization_user"'
```

A user is tied to one (or more) organization through `Membership`. I can get the detail for a user through `UserReadSerializer` which looks like this

class UserReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
organization = MembershipSerializer(source='membership_set', many=True)

class Meta:
    model = UserModel
    fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'organization')
```

Thus for a user id 1, I get the following response:

```
{
    "email": "******@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Hello",
    "last_name": "User",
    "username": "myuser",
    "organization": [
        {
            "name": "Org1",
            "url": "https://org1.net/",
            "year": 1893,
            "position": "position1",
            "is_admin": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Org2",
            "url": "https://org2.net/",
            "year": 1983,
            "position": "position2",
            "is_admin": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to modify the user organization detail, for example, the position through PUT method and for this I am passing the edit data in a similar format as:

```
{
    "email": "******@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Hello",
    "last_name": "User",
    "username": "myuser",
    "organization": [
        {
            "name": "Org1",
            "position": "changed_position1",
            "is_admin": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Org2",
            "position": "changed_position2",
            "is_admin": true
        }
    ]
}
```

My serializer for this looks like:

class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

```
username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
first_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
last_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
email = serializers.EmailField(required=False)

organization = MembershipSerializer(source='membership_set', many=True, required=False)
```

But I cannot access the organization_name. All I get is `position` and `is_admin` field. Is there something I am missing here? I am using Django 1.11. Thank you for any help!

Comment: I think you should read this doc, [Writable Nested Serializers - DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: How is your `MembershipSerializer` implemented?